# Two problems with ConjugateGradient

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to solve a maximization problem for which I give you the code and try to step by step show you were it broke down. The first issue is that I have a constrained problem, which I try to solve by projecting back into the feasible set and the second is that I encounter an Overflow error.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
    Y[t1_, t2_] := L^(1/a) t1^(1/b) t2^(1/c);
    U[x_] = x - (Exp[-gamma x] - 1);

Maximand[Cn_, Dn_, whp_, whh_, wcp_, wch_] = (U[Cn] - ((disp + Zc) wcp^2 + (dish + Zc) wch^2) + 
    beta U[((X - Cn  + k1 Dn - ((chp + ZH) whp^2  + (chh + ZH) whh^2)   - (k - 
             pn) Y[whp + delta wcp, whh + delta wch] - (Exp[-alpha X] - 1))  - 
        Exp[-alpha (X - Cn + k1 Dn - ((chp + ZH) whp^2  + (chh + ZH) whh^2)   - (k - 
                pn) Y[whp + delta wcp, whh + delta wch] -   (Exp[-alpha X] - 
               1))  + ((alpha Y[whp + delta wcp, whh + delta wch] sigma)^2)/2 + ( (alpha Dn sigma2)^2)/ 2])]  )  ;

a = 2; b = 2; c = 2; delta = 1; ZH = 1; Zc = 1; chp = 1; chh = 1; X = 30; alpha = 0.3; disp = 1; dish = 1; k = 3; pn = 10; sigma = 1.5; L = 10; gamma = 1; beta = 0.7; k1 = 2; sigma2 = 1.1;
```

My first go was:

```
FindMaximum[ Maximand[Cn, Dn, whp, whh, wcp, wch], {{Cn, 50}, {Dn, 2}, {whp, 2}, {whh, 2}, {wcp, 2}, {wch, 2}}, Method -> "ConjugateGradient"]
```

This led to ""The function value Overflow[] is not a real number at {Cn,Dn,whp,whh,wcp,wch} = {52.2065,17.9307,14.691,14.691,-2.96088,-2.96088}. "

Therefore I tried to project it back to the feasible set (feasible set as in below function):

```
FindMaximum[
 Maximand[Cn, Max[Dn, 0], Max[whp, 0], Max[whh, 0], Max[wcp, 0], Max[wch, 0]], {{Cn, 50}, {Dn, 2}, {whp, 2}, {whh, 2}, {wcp, 2}, {wch, 2}}, Method -> "ConjugateGradient"]
```

However, I ended up with the same error.

On top of that I always run into an overflwo problem. I guess the problem is this term:

```
- Exp[-alpha (X - Cn + k1 Dn - ((chp + ZH) whp^2  + (chh + ZH) whh^2)   - (k - pn) Y[whp + delta wcp, whh + delta wch] -   (Exp[-alpha X] - 1))  + ((alpha Y[whp + delta wcp, whh + delta wch] sigma)^2)/2 + ( (alpha Dn sigma2)^2)/ 2]
```

However, as I am trying to maximize the "ConjugateGradient" should not go in the direction that this term becomes large.

Do you have an idea to get this going?

Answer (score 1):

Do the results of [NMaximize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html) look reasonable?

```
    NMaximize[{Maximand[Cn, Dn, whp, whh, wcp, wch], whh > 0 && wcp > 0 && wch > 0}, {Cn, Dn, whp, whh, wcp, wch}]
```